# List of Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 DF that have in common some elements, and differentiates on 1 data. These DF are added into a list with the function append.
How do i re organise the list into a new DF with the data put in columns ?

The 2 DF are like below and are added with append

```
import pandas as pd
a=[]

r1={'date' : ['2003-01-31','2003-01-31'],'name' :['mod','dom'],'fib' :[2,3]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(r1,columns=['date','name','fib'])


r2={'date' : ['2003-01-31','2003-01-31'],'name' :['dom','mod'],'bif' :[5,7]}
df2=pd.DataFrame(r2,columns=['date','name','bif'])

a.append(df1)
a.append(df2)
a
```

Then i map the list a in a new DF

```
z=pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame,a))
z
```

How do i re organize z that needs only two rows ?

The output i expect is

```
r3={'date':['2003-01-31','2003-01-31'],'name' :['mod','dom'],'fib':[2,3],'bif':[7,5]}
pd.DataFrame(r3)
```

Comment: can you show a sample of your expected output?

Comment: I added the desired output. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `z` , I would do:

```
z=pd.concat([i.set_index(['date','name']) for i in a],axis=1).reset_index()
print(z)
```

---

```
         date name  fib  bif
0  2003-01-31  dom    3    5
1  2003-01-31  mod    2    7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using pd.merge

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['name', 'date'])
```

Results:

```
    date    name    fib bif
0   2003-01-31  mod 2   7
1   2003-01-31  dom 3   5
```

Comment: What will you do if this is the DF named 'z' instead of merging DF1 & DF2 ?

Comment: I'm confused by the question, this result is achieved by merging df1 and df2 from your examples above. If you want to name the result z you can do z=df1.merge(df2, on=['name', 'date'])